# Сохранение файлов в Tomcat

Tags: файлы, tomcat

Клиенты приложения сохраняют файлы. Заливаю их прямо в директорию самого приложения. При новом деплое war-ника  загруженные пользователями файлы тю-тю(удаляются). Подскажите решение.

Comment: А бывают какие-нибудь репозитории для war-ников?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте в папке `webapps` отдельную папку для файлов пользователей, например, "uploads" и сохраняйте файлы в ней. При таком подходе файлы, во-первых, не будут удаляться при развёртывании приложения, а во-вторых, будут доступны для скачивания по пути `http(s)://IP/uploads/some-file.jpg`, без каких-либо дополнительных манипуляций.

Если предполагается большое количество файлов, то лучше автоматически создавать дочерние каталоги, например по дате и времени. Будет выглядеть примерно так: `http(s)://IP/uploads/2017/05/29/23/some-file.jpg`, где путь состоит из ГОД/МЕСЯЦ/ДЕНЬ/ЧАС. При загрузке файла берётся текущее время и формируется соответствующий путь. Проверяется наличие каталога, если его нет - то создаётся, затем сохраняется файл.

Доступ к папке "соседнего" приложения можно получить так:

```
String dir = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
            + "/../uploads/2017/05/29/23/");
```

где ".." - указание подняться на одну папку выше, от корня приложения "/"

Comment: Спасибо! А как сохранить файл за пределы приложения?

Comment: String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/image");
File fileSaveDir = new File(appPath);
Cохраняет в приложение

Comment: спасибо @bobzer

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов несколько:

1. Сохраняйте в базу данных
2. Сохраняйте в корзину на S3
3. Сохраняйте в выделенное место на диске (которое не будет очищаться при развертывании)

Comment: Сохранение в БД - опасный вариант, в плане последующей поддержки Системы. БД разрастается до десятков и сотен Гб, в результате многие действия над ней становятся очень проблематичными. Создание бакапа может длиться часы а то и сутки, если по какой-то причине надо "переехать" на другой сервер, то Систему придётся останавливать надолго. Да просто операция добавления столбца в таблицу с блобами может длиться неколько часов (были реальные случаи в одной из версий MySQL).