# Как создать связку Apache http server - Tomcat?

Tags: apache, сервер, tomcat

Появилась задача создать связку Клиент-Tomcat-ApacheHttpServer. Если с первым звеном все ясно, то со вторым есть проблемы. Необходимо наладить связь между Apache Http Server с Tomcat да так, чтобы была возможность передавать картинки(до 20мб) как можно быстрее.

Был ли у кого-нибудь опыт в подобном?

Comment: А зачем? Томкат прекрасно сделает сам всё, что нужно. Возможно, вам стоит разобраться с ним?

Comment: Добавление Apache Http, теоретически, может иметь смысл только если он будет находится на другом сервере и отдавать картинки оттуда, а не с сервера с Tomcat-ом. За счёт такого решения с сервера приложений будет снята часть нагрузки. Если же они оба находятся на одном сервере, то разница в скорости отдачи картинок вряд ли заметно увеличится, зато сам Apache Http потребует дополнительные ресурсы. Попробуйте это решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672151/183597 . Какое бы решение не приняли, в любом случае проведите нагрузочные тесты.

Comment: настраиваете Apache как proxy и все, а дальше можете использовать любой сервер - Tomcat, Jetty