# tomcat & добавление файлов в папку webapp'a

Tags: tomcat

Раньше создавал приложение не по `maven-archetypes-webapp`, а собственноручно, и сервлеты прописывал без аннотаций, а через **web.xml**, компилировал классы вручную.

В **server.xml** у меня прописано, что домен `mydomain.com` базируется в папке **../webapps/mywebapp**:

```
<Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context
        path=""
        docBase="mywebapp"
        reloadable="true"
    />
</Host>
```

Я мог положить любой файл прямо в **../webapps/mywebapp/myfile.txt** и файл был бы доступен по адресу `http://mydomain.com/myfile.txt`, аналогично, если бы я создал **../webapps/mywebapp/folder/myfile.txt**, то файл был бы доступен по `http://mydomain.com/folder/myfile.txt`.

Сейчас я создаю проект по архетипу мавен, собираю его в `.war`, отключаю томкат, бросаю `.war` в папку **webapps**, включаю томкат, и всё. Но теперь описанное выше не работает: поступаю аналогично, бросаю файл в ту же папку, и он не доступен уже по такому же адресу, и даже по `http://mydomain.com/webappname/myfile.txt`, по которому проект также доступен.

Однако, если я сразу добавлю файл в **../IdeaProjects/Captcha/src/main/webapp/myfile.txt**, затем соберу `.war` и задеплою проект, то на сервере **myfile.txt** окажется по тому же пути, но уже будет доступен по нужному адресу.

Почему так? То же и с редактированием файлов: допустим, у меня внутри проекта лежат settings.properties (в IDEA помещённые в **../IdeaProjects/mywebapp/src/main/resources/settings.properties**), после деплоя они лежат в **../tomcat8/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes/settings.properties**, и читаются при каждом запросе - но если что-то в них поменять, в силу это не вступит, хоть файл и изменится, но читаться будет старая версия.

Даже причина не так важна: я бы хотел, чтобы работало как ранее: я мог спокойно по sftp в папочку закинуть нужный мне файл, и чтобы он был доступен сразу же, и не нужно было редеплоить/перезапускать томкат/etc.

[Этот совет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672100/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-tomcat) не подходит: перехожу по любому из доменов + путь, подключенных к серверу, либо по `http://mydomain.com/webappname/directory/file.txt` и так далее, всё равно `404` ошибка, хотя создал в папке **webapps** папку directory и поместил туда файл. Права на папке и файле для теста `777`.

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: вот если бы эжто были отдельные вопросы, то отвечать было бы легче. как вы загружаете **settings.properties** в коде?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman `properties.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("settings.properties"));`. Если знаете, что ответить, то ответьте хоть на один из двух вопросов. И вообще, я не думаю, что они так сильно различаются. Суть одна: после деплоя war-файла, изменения файлов (включая добавление новых) игнорируется томкатом.

Comment: в каком месте вызывается это код?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman в конструкторе класса. Я его статически объявляю во всех классах, в которых использую. И да: это не самая важная часть вопроса. Меня более волнует добавление новых файлов.

Comment: просто, сервлет создается при старте приложения и поэтому изменения после старта и не видны.

Comment: правильный метод: добавлять файлы в какую-нибудь БД (или ее подобие), которая находится вне вашего приложения.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman мне, в принципе, не очень нужно, чтобы изменения учитывались. Но вот новые файлы чтобы были видны,  нужно.